# MUL operator Vs IMUL operator in NASM

Tags: operators, nasm

Is there any reason why MUL operator is only in single operand form?
IMUL operator can be in three different forms (with one, two or three operands) and this is much more convenient. From the technical point of view I don't see any reason why MUL operator can't be in two/three operands form.

Comment: Can someone also chime in on what the difference between MUL and IMUL is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the bytecodes that are output. In the pre-80286 world there were too many opcodes so the Intel engineers were finding ways to overcome the problem. One solution was to extend the portion of the bytecode that specifies the operation (multiplication in this case) into the portion of the bytecode that encoded the first operand. This obviously meant that only one operand could by supported when executing the MUL opcode. Because a multiplication requires two operands, they solved the problem by hard coding into the processor that the first operand would always be the eax register. Later processors supported bytecodes that were of multiple lengths wich allowed them to encode more data into a single command. This allowed them to make the IMUL opcode much more useful.

There is an interesting parallel today with the IP addresses running out.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that there is no need for the others modes with `MUL`. `MUL` does unsigned word * word to double word. `IMUL` with one operand does the same thing for signed.  For word*word to lower word sign does not matter so there is no need for this mode with `MUL`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that NASM doesn't support it - on the CPU, the signed version of the instruction simply supports more variants than the unsigned version.

Answer (score 1):

Three-operand `imul`, as well as two-operand forms with an immediate operand (which is an alias to the three-operand form) were introduced with the 186 instruction set. Later, the 386 added two-operand forms with a register and an r/m operand.

All of these new forms have in common that the multiplication is done either with 16 bits times 16 bits (possibly from sign-extended 8-bit immediate) with a 16 bit result, or 32 bits times 32 bits with a 32 bit result. In these cases, the low 16 or low 32 bits of the result is the same for `imul` as they would be for an equivalent `mul`, only the flags (CF and OF) may differ. So a separate multi-operand `mul` isn't needed. Presumably the designers went with the mnemonic `imul` because the forms with an 8 bit immediate do sign-extend that immediate.